# Is it possible to share a value from remote git to local git?

Tags: git, hook, git-remote

I need to perform some calculations on the server side of a git repository, but I also want to share the result with locals.

I created a server-side `post-receive` hook which performs some actions, then store the result in a file into the `info` directory. Such result can be sent easily to the client during the hook execution, client will receive it in the push result message, but I want a client to be capable to get it on request. Is it possible?

Comment: It's probably possible in some way, but this is probably not a good use of your version control system. Could you tell us what the purpose of this is? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: @Schwern Customer want to know how many pushes have been done to the repository ever

Comment: Do you need to send the information back to the local repo? Could the post-receive hook send it somewhere else? Maybe a simple POST to a webhook?

Comment: I have to put it in the build process, in order to generate a version string with this value.

Comment: Due to the distributed nature of Git, what you're asking for is probably impossible. You could have the server edit and commit a file every time there's a push, but that's really abusing the push process. IMO the number of internal pushes during development is of dubious use in a version number, it conveys no more useful information about the release than incrementing a number. Perhaps consider something like [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/)? Is it necessary to have and up-to-date version string during local development? Or is that only necessary in the release process?